# Replace values in a 2d list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to replace all of the values in a 2D list.

For example, if `list=[[2,3,4],[3,5,6]]`,

I want to replace all of the values so the new list is `list=[['','',''],['','','']]`

Answer (score 1):

```
items = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
emptyItem = lambda x: ''
emptyItemList = lambda x: list(map(emptyItem, x))
emptied = list(map(emptyItemList, items))
print(emptied)
```

or, in one line:

```
emptied = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: '', x)), items))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
[['' for _ in sub] for sub in list]
```

You probably shouldn't name a variable `list`.